# Determine whether a "Long tail" exists in a dataset

Tags: sql, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am working with a 200MB database that stores feedback from users about products in different years (Assume that 1 record = 1 feedback). The DB has the following schema
[image]

- asin is a unique identifier of a product.

I am trying to determine if in any given year 20% of the products("asin") are accountable for more than 65% of the all feedbacks in that year ("Long-tail phenomena").

I tried to refer to the ASIN and the Year as a unique key and assign the value 1 to each time they key appeared. Then I would aggregate these values and would check if the first 20 ASIN count is bigger than 65% of all the feedback count.
The following is an example of my code in PySpark:

```
reviews_rdd = reviews_df_split_date.rdd
print(type(reviews_rdd))

reviews_rdd\
.map(lambda r: ((r.asin, r.Year),1))\
.reduceByKey(lambda v1, v2: v1 + v2)\
.collect()
```

which produced the following output:  [image]

That's where I got stucked and didn't know how to group all ASIN in a given year and check the ASIN with the most feedbacks.

How can I check whether if less than 20% of the products in any given year account for over than 65% of all the feedbacks given in that year?

Comment: Thanks for your question! [Please don't post screenshots of text/data/code/errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/15405732). They can't be searched or copied, or even consumed by users of adaptive technologies like screen readers. Instead, paste the code as text directly into your question/answer. If you select it and click the {} button or Ctrl+K the code block will be indented by four spaces, which will cause it to be rendered as code.